# Must declare the scalar variable @RECEIVABLESDATA

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this SQL code that I'm using to insert 3 tables at a time dynamically. When I try to run it, I get this message

> Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure InsertData, Line 28
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@RECEIVABLESDATA".

Any ideas?

```
USE [PantaRei]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertData] 
@RECEIVABLESDATA RECEIVABLESTABLE READONLY,
@DILUTIONSDATA DILUTIONSTABLE READONLY,
@ACCOUNTABLESDATA ACCOUNTABLESTABLE READONLY,
@TABLE1 VARCHAR(MAX),
@TABLE2 VARCHAR(MAX),
@TABLE3 VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    DECLARE @CMD nvarchar(345)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SET @TABLE1 = RTRIM(@TABLE1)
    SET @TABLE2 = RTRIM(@TABLE2)
    SET @TABLE3 = RTRIM(@TABLE3)

    SET @CMD =

        'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE1) +
        'SELECT * FROM [DBO].' + QUOTENAME(@RECEIVABLESDATA)

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD

    SET @CMD =

        'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE2) +
        'SELECT * FROM [DBO].' + QUOTENAME(@DILUTIONSDATA)

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD

    SET @CMD =

        'INSERT INTO '+ QUOTENAME(@TABLE3) + 
        'SELECT * FROM [DBO].' + QUOTENAME(@ACCOUNTABLESDATA)
END
```

Comment: How is RECEIVABLESTABLE defined?  I suspect this is the problem.

Comment: Are these first three parameters Table types and you're trying to use them as TVPs? If so, I don't believe you can reference a TVP from dynamic SQL, it's kind of like a table variable in that respect - not visible to the dynamic SQL scope.

Comment: I used a User defined table type                                                                         USE [PantaRei]
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedTableType [dbo].[ReceivablesTable]    Script Date: 15-08-2012 18:53:24 ******/
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[ReceivablesTable] AS TABLE(
 [FileID] [int] NULL,
 [SheetType] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
 [SellerCompany] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
GO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use temp tables:

```
  SELECT * INTO #t1 FROM @RECEIVABLESDATA;

  SET @CMD =

        'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE1) +
        'SELECT * FROM #t1';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD
```

Also [here is the other way](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/08/passing-table-variable-into-dynamic-sql.html). Check if it works in your MS SQL version:

```
SET @CMD =

        'INSERT INTO ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE1) +
        'SELECT * FROM @RECEIVABLESDATA';

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @CMD, N'@RECEIVABLESDATA RECEIVABLESDATA READONLY', @RECEIVABLESDATA;
```